# Gojs rendering diagram in memory and converting into svg

Tags: gojs

We have a requirement where a users selects different checkboxes and based on those checkbox a diagram will be downloaded as svg files.

My plan is get the all the data based on ids checked in checkbox, render the the gojs diagram in memory and convert the so respective svg by calling makeSVG.

Will the above plan work? When drawing in memory will the different events trigger like documentchange, intiallayout complete?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work, either on the client side or on the server side.

For a demonstration of the former, see http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html.

For a demonstration of the latter, see http://gojs.net/latest/intro/serverSideImages.html, although that generates an image rather than SVG.  But you could just call makeSvg instead and not use an IMG element at all.